# Alignment of different-sized objects in Row

Tags: graphics

I would like to Align several distinct boxes so that the top of each one is at the same level. For example:

```
framed1 := Framed["", ImageSize -> {100, 100}]
framed2 := Framed["", ImageSize -> {250, 75}]
framed3 := Framed["", ImageSize -> {50, 50}]

Row[{framed1, framed2, framed3}, "   "]
```

[image]

Ideally, all three boxes should have their top line begin at the same place as the first one, instead of being centered.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`BaselinePosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BaselinePosition.html)

```
framed1 := Framed["", ImageSize -> {100, 100}, BaselinePosition -> Top]
framed2 := Framed["", ImageSize -> {250, 75}, BaselinePosition -> Top]
framed3 := Framed["", ImageSize -> {50, 50}, BaselinePosition -> Top]

Row[{framed1, framed2, framed3}, "   "]
```

[image]

It may help to review the other [`Framed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Framed.html) options.

Answer (score 5):

One may also find [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html) useful:

```
framed1 := Framed["", ImageSize -> {100, 100}]
framed2 := Framed["", ImageSize -> {250, 75}]
framed3 := Framed["", ImageSize -> {50, 50}]

Grid[{{framed1, framed2, framed3}}, Alignment -> Top]
```

[image]

If a special separator is needed it can be [`Riffle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Riffle.html)'d in:

```
Grid[{{framed1, framed2, framed3} ~Riffle~ "⊙"}, Alignment -> Top]
```

[image]